# Conectar a Gmail con PHP y IMAP

Tags: php, gmail, imap

Sucede que intento establecer la conexión para interactuar entre php y gmail con IMP y me sale el Error: No such host as pop.gmail.com/imap.gmail.com.

Mi código es:

```
$host="{pop.gmail.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}";
$host="{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}";

$user="---";
$pass="---";

if($mbox=imap_open( $host, $user, $pass )){

    echo "<h3>Conectado</h3>\n";
    imap_close($mbox);

} else{

    echo "<h3>Error! ". imap_last_error()."</h3>\n";

}
```

He probado con los 2 $host

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero hacer lo siguiente:

1. usar el certificado inseguro:

   $connect_to = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
2. Permitir a **Gmail** ser accedido por aplicaciones no seguras:

   [Aplicaciones no Seguras Gmail](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)
3. Fin

Espero te sirva..!!